# (не) упомянутый : слитно или раздельно?

Tags: слитно-раздельно

Например: приводим ранее не упомянутый список отличий: цвет, вкус, запах...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

...*Ранее не упомянутый список*... - раздельно, потому что есть зависимое слово "ранее".